# Understanding Spark UI details for a small pyspark snippet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-ui

I am trying to understand the job, stage and task details shown in SparkUI for the following pyspark snippet

```
# Disabling adaptive execution to see 200 shuffle partitions show up
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled', 'false')
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a','b','c']))
df.groupBy('a').agg({'b': 'sum'}).withColumnRenamed('sum(b)', 'b').orderBy(F.desc('b')).collect()
```

[image]

This is making sense as I am noticing two shuffle exchanges corresponding to `group-by` and `order-by` operations. I am guessing `HashAggregate` in the first block (before the first shuffle) is a local aggregation done by each task (like combiner in map-reduce). Is that correct?

For job & stage level details I have several questions.

- Why there are two jobs as there is only one action `collect`?

[image]

- Stage-5 & 6 (job-3) appears to be transformation for `group-by`. If that is the case then I can't make sense of Stage 7,8,9 (job-4) as I am seeing two more exchanges there. Am I not understanding it correctly?
  [image]
  [image]
- I am also expecting output of stage-6 to be fed into stage-8 instead `stage-7` becoming the predecessor of stage-8. Also what is the role of `parallelize->mapPartitions...->` in stage-7? What transformation (in pyspark snippet) does it correspond to?
- Is it getting skipped because corresponding data is found in cache?

Any help will be really appreciated.